# Overload an operator twice

Tags: c++

It's possible to overload the same operator twice on C++?

When I try to overload the + operator using the return type as a base, the compiler show me an error.

```
bigint.h:41:9: error: ‘std::string BigInt::operator+(BigInt)’ cannot be overloaded
bigint.h:40:9: error: with ‘BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt)’
```

This is my code:

.h:

```
BigInt operator + (BigInt);
string operator + (BigInt);
```

.cc:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator + (BigInt M){

    if (this->number.size() != M.number.size())
        fixLength (this->number, M.number);

    // Call Sum;
    this->number = Sum (this->number, M.number);

    return (*this);
}

string BigInt::operator + (Bigint M){

    // Call BigInt overload +;
}
```

Edit: Apparently I cannot overload the same operator twice using the return type as a base. Suggestions?

Comment: No this is not possible. The compiler can't know which version you want, it deducts it from the parameters.

Comment: You *can* overload many times, but not by the return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you cannot overload beased on return type alone. So this is fine:

```
Foo operator+(const Foo&, const Foo&);
Foo operator+(const char*, double);
```

but this is not:

```
Foo operator+(const Foo&, const Foo&);
Bar operator+(const Foo&, const Foo&);
```

But most of the time there are valid and simple solutions to a given problem. For instance, in a situation like yours, where you want the following to work:

```
Foo a, b;
Foo c = a + b;
Bar bar = a + b;
```

then a common strategy is to either give `Bar` an implicit converting constructor:

```
struct Bar
{
  Bar(const Foo& foo) { .... }
};
```

or give `Foo` a conversion operator:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit operator Bar() { .... }
  ....
};
```

Note you can't mark the operator `explicit` if you don't have a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 3):

method overload in C++ is by argument list, not the return value.. so in your case, the two methods are ambiguous and the compiler can't tell which one to use (they have the same argument list)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't overload based on the return type.

From standard docs., Sec 13.1.2,

```
Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.
```

What this means is that methods can be overloading only if they differ by parameters. As with C++, a method's return type is not considered part of the method signature.

Check Wiki for [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for more details