# Overloading * multiplication operator twice as a member function?

Tags: c++, overloading

Scroll down for TL:DR.

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260910/overload-an-operator-twice) one, but has some differences. It concerns overloading the `*` operator twice for a class called `jVector`, which simply represents a two-dimensional cartesian vector.

The first type of multiplication is `jVector * jVector`, or a [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The second type is multiplication by a real number, `double * jVector`. This simply returns a vector with its entries multiplied by the double.

Here is some code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
class jVector{
    public:
        double x, y;

        jVector(double x_val = 0., double y_val = 0.){
            x = x_val;
            y = y_val;
        }

        //Operator overload functions
        //[...]

        //F1: Dot product (WORKS)
        double operator* (jVector& factor){
            double result;
            result = x * factor.x;
            result += y * factor.y;
            return result;
        }

        //F2: Real number multiplication (DOES NOT WORK)
        jVector operator* (double f){
            jVector result;
            result.x = x * f;
            result.y = y * f;
            return result;
        }

        //[...]
}

//F3: As a non-member (WORKS)
jVector operator* (double f, jVector V){
    jVector result;
    result.x = V.x * f;
    result.y = V.y * f;
    return result;
}
```

The three relevant functions are marked `F1`, `F2` and `F3`. The functions `F2` and `F3` are never defined at the same time (I comment out one of them to test the other).

Here is the result of trying to express something like `2.0 * Foo`, where `Foo` is a vector of type `jVector`. The operation works as expected when using `F3`, the function which is defined outside the class. However, when using only `F2`, the member function, an error is raised which says `no match for 'operator*' in '2 * Foo'`.

This is the same type of error which you get if you don't overload an operator at all, suggesting that I didn't define `F2` properly, or `F2` is conflicting with `F1`.

I'm fairly certain my problem is different from the one in the [question I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260910/overload-an-operator-twice) earlier, since `F1` and `F2` have different return types **and** argument types.

**TL:DR**

So here's my question: why am I able to overload `*` twice, only as long as one of them is defined as a non-member function? Why can't both overload functions be members of the class?

Comment: `F2` defines `jVector * double`, not `double * jVector`.  C++ doesn't assume those two operations have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as a member function because your F2 alternative takes a `jVector` as the first operand ALWAYS (it is a member function, so you don't have a choice of what the first argument is - it is `jVector *this` [hidden by the language]). The compiler could in theory allow the two operands to swap place (it could for `x * 2.0` convert to `2.0 * x` for regular math operations, but since operator overloads aren't made to be "swapped around", that wouldn't be very good if the compiler DID re-arrange them)

For the first operand to be `double`, you need a freestanding function.

Answer (score 2):

For member function operator overloads, the **first operand** must be an object of the class.  The parameter of the overloaded function is the second operand. So:

```
double operator* (double f){
```

only applies to the case where you are doing `a_vector * a_double`, and not to `a_double * a_vector`.

For this reason (and others) it's generally better to use non-member functions for overloaded operators.  The way I would suggest doing it is:

```
// member function
jVector & jVector::operator*=( double f )
{
    x *= f;
    y *= f;
    return *this;
}

// free functions
jVector operator* (double f, jVector V) { return V *= f; }
jVector operator* (jVector V, double f) { return V *= f; }
```